# How to open URL while passing POST data with jQuery?

Tags: jquery

```
                $('body').append($('<form/>') 
            .attr({'action': 'https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr', 'method': 'post', 'id', 'btn_submit'})  
                    .append($('<input/>')     
                    .attr({'type': 'hidden', 'name': 'cmd', 'value': "_s-xclick"})   )  
                    .append($('<input/>')    
                    .attr({'type': 'hidden', 'name': 'hosted_button_id', 'value': "SDFSDFFGHFGH"})   
                    ) 
                    ).find('#btn_submit').submit();
```

I have error in this code. I like to know where I missing code. please help me out.

Answer (score 1):

It appears to be from the call to `.attr`. You are using a comma instead of a colon at the end, the 'id' property is assigned the value 'btn_submit', so it should be:

```
{'action': 'https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr', 'method': 'post', 'id': 'btn_submit'}
```